# Error while installing ruby-serialport gem

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, serial-port

I am using `rvm` version :

`rvm 1.17.9 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

Ruby version :

`ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]`

I am getting an error while installing 
`gem install ruby-serialport`

Error is : `Failed to build gem native extension.`

More details : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1555079/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an updated version of the gem on github:
https://github.com/hparra/ruby-serialport

Also available on RubyGems:
http://rubygems.org/gems/serialport

The one you installed `ruby-serialport` is v0.7.0, the updated `serialport` gem is v1.1.0, so you probably want to give that a try:

```
gem install serialport
```